# image name in xml child more than one and get limitation with php

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

i have xml the other array i got it but first one cant how can i solve this

Xml structure like this and get an error code in xml to php First one is not array the second one is array

i Coudnt get the first image children `"sitename/11.jpg"`

Xml like this

```
 [images] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [image] => Array ( [0] => sitename/15.jpg [1] => sitename/16.jpg [2] => sitename/17.jpg [3] => sitename/18.jpg ) ) )

 [images] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [image] => sitename/11.jpg ))
```

```
<root>
<result>
<node>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image>sitename/15.jpg</image><image>sitename/16.jpg</image><image>sitename/17.jpg</image><image>sitename/18.jpg</image>
</images>
</node>
<node>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image>sitename/11.jpg</image>
</images>
</node>
  </result>
      </root>
```

```
function solve_something($xml, $destination)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $items = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $products = array();
    $product_data = array();
    $row = 1;
foreach ($items['result']['node'] as $item) {
    $product_data['Categories'] = 'categories';
    if (isset($item['images']['image'])) {
        if (is_array($item['images']['image'])) {
            foreach ($item['images']['image'] as $key => $image) {
                $key++;
                if ($key <= 4) {
                    $image_name = 'image' . $key;
                    $product_data[$image_name] = isset($image) ? $image : null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $product_data['image'] = isset($image) ? $image : null;
        }
    }

$path = createXML($products, $destination);
return $path;
}
The other function code its create the xml file

function createXML($data, $destination)
{

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("root"));
    foreach ($data as $key => $product) {

        $productA = $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement('product'));
        foreach ($product as $key1 => $val) {
            if (!empty($val)) {
                if ($key1 == 'price' || $key1 == 'tax' || $key1 == 'stockAmount') {
                    $productA->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement($key1, $val));
                } else {
                    $ProductKey = $productA->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement($key1));
                    $ProductKey->appendChild($xmlDoc->createCDATASection($val));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    fn_rm($destination);
    $xmlDoc->save($destination);
    return $destination;
}
```

Code create

```
<root>
  <product>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image1>sitename/15.jpg
<image2>sitename/16.jpg
<image3>sitename/17.jpg
</images>
  </product>
  <product>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image1>sitename/15.jpg
<image2>sitename/16.jpg
<image3>sitename/17.jpg
<image4>sitename/18.jpg
</images>
  </product>
</root>
```

But i want

```
<root>
  <product>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image1>sitename/15.jpg
<image2>sitename/16.jpg
<image3>sitename/17.jpg
</images>
  </product>
  <product>
<categories>somecategory<categories/>
<images>
<image1>sitename/11.jpg
</images>
  </product>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code

- If you want to have 3 images, this part `if ($key <= 4) {` should be lesser or equal than 2.
- You don't really have to return anything (or you want to check for false), as you are writing a file, as the `save` function returns `the number of bytes written or false if an error occurred.`
- Using `$key++;` like this in the foreach can also be done using a for loop where you can use `$i` to append after `image`
- Not sure why you want to use `createCDATASection` but I have left that part out to get the desired result
- As you have multiple sections of `node`, you may use an `$product_data` array per iteration to add the values to and after the foreach add `$product_data` to the `$products` array to prevent overwriting the values for every loop.

The updated code might look like

```
function solve_something($xml, $destination)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $items = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $products = array();

    foreach ($items['result']['node'] as $item) {
        $product_data = array();
        $category = $item["categories"];
        $product_data["categories"] = $category;
        if (isset($item['images']['image'])) {
            if (is_array($item['images']['image'])) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($item['images']['image']); $i++) {
                    if ($i < 3) $product_data["image" . ($i + 1)] = $item['images']['image'][$i];
                }
            } else $product_data["image1"] = $item['images']['image'];
        }
        $products[] = $product_data;
    }
    createXML($products, $destination);
}

function createXML($data, $destination)
{
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("root"));

    foreach ($data as $key => $product) {
        $productA = $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement('product'));
        $imagesElm = $xmlDoc->createElement('images');
        foreach ($product as $key1 => $val) {
            if ($key1 == 'price' || $key1 == 'tax' || $key1 == 'stockAmount' || $key1 === "categories") {
                $productA->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement($key1, $val));
            } elseif (substr($key1, 0, 5) === "image") {
                $imagesElm->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement($key1, $val));
            }
        }
        $productA->appendChild($imagesElm);
    }

    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    $xmlDoc->save($destination);
}

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <result>
        <node>
            <categories>somecategory</categories>
            <images>
                <image>sitename/15.jpg</image>
                <image>sitename/16.jpg</image>
                <image>sitename/17.jpg</image>
                <image>sitename/18.jpg</image>
            </images>
        </node>
        <node>
            <categories>somecategory</categories>
            <images>
                <image>sitename/11.jpg</image>
            </images>
        </node>
    </result>
</root>
XML;

solve_something($xml, "result.xml");
```

The xml in `result.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <product>
    <categories>somecategory</categories>
    <images>
      <image1>sitename/15.jpg</image1>
      <image2>sitename/16.jpg</image2>
      <image3>sitename/17.jpg</image3>
    </images>
  </product>
  <product>
    <categories>somecategory</categories>
    <images>
      <image1>sitename/11.jpg</image1>
    </images>
  </product>
</root>
```

Comment: xml dont have only image child soo that reason i use this code. But code is not working i only change solve_something function. Still image looks like the first one. :(

Comment: The code works for the example data. Did you use the full code?

Comment: i don't use createxml function, only for this xml . So that reason can we solve different situation?

Comment: @crazyshark You don't have to pull al the statement into the createxml function. You can reuse the mechanism by using the code in another function to build the xml.

Comment: i f i use your code gives this in xml description etc.. cant create.  <root>
  <product>
    <images/>
  </product>
  <product>
    <images/>
  </product>
</root>

Comment: @crazyshark See the output when I echo the final xml https://3v4l.org/mocpB

Comment: Thanks but i donT2t understand why still image child get the other image child. maybe put somewhere unset i don't understand :((

Comment: $products[] = $product_data;
        unset($product_data); i use this problem is solve thanks